# How to clear input value and redirect at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to redirect to Google Search page and clear the input field at the same time.

This is the code ([a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxbowu0f/)):

```js
function eraseText() {
  document.getElementById("comp-kofkqaf0input").value = "";
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform example" method="get" name="searchform" target="top">
  <input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search google" id="comp-kofkqaf0input" value="" style="padding-left: 18px;" name="q" value="" required>
  <button class="button1" type="submit" onclick="eraseText()"><span class="material-icons-outlined">search</span>Search</button>
</form>
```

However, the HTML simply erase my input field value without redirecting me to Google Search page.

I need when I clicked the button, it redirect you to Google Search page and clear the value in the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add ID to your form (to allow easier location), and then in eraseText() you should add:

```
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

So end result will be more like this:

```js
function eraseText()
{
    document.getElementById("comp-kofkqaf0input").value = "";
    document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform example" method="get" name="searchform" target="top" id="searchForm" >
  <input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="" >
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Search google" id="comp-kofkqaf0input" value="" style="padding-left: 18px;" name="q" value="" required >
  <button class="button1" type="submit" onclick="eraseText()"><span class="material-icons-outlined">search</span>Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should change the javascript function upside down.
It would like:
`function eraseText()
{
    document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
    document.getElementById("comp-kofkqaf0input").value = "";
}
`